The name of that manga about some a guy who is a teen with a really powerful gauntlet and his aunt or something woman who also was a vampire?
I'm looking for an manga about some young guy who lives with his aunt I think it was: the kid had spiky dark hair and was immortal, or at least had powerful regenerating capabilities, he also had some really powerful gauntlet. The woman i think she was a powerful vampire and she kinda acted as his guardian.
In the first episode the guy encounters and fights some girl who came to kill him i think, she used swords if i remember corrctly, but she then joined them and I think she sticks with them throughout the series.
I'm pretty sure the guy was trying to peep on the woman in an outdoor bath, by climbing up a cliff as well.

Was this full colour or mostly black & white? And in roughly which year did you read it?

i remember having read it a while before the pandemic, i would say around 2017-2018, as for the color, i am 80% certain it was in black and white.

I just realized it might have been an anime :/

Some element make me strongly thinking about UQ holder from Ken Akamatsu.

https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Manga/UQHolder
The only thing missing is the gauntlet, and even then at some point, The MC arms are 'morphing' due to magic, in a way that can be seen as gauntlets.
This story was a stealth sequel (that end up dropping the stealth part) to Negima! Magister Negi Magi
The MC is indeed immortal (vampire with absurd regeneration), and he start the story as ward of another vampire (a blond woman), and he might refer her as his aunt (either between them and to others).
Being an Akamatsu work, outdoor bath (and scantly clad women) are a given.

YES, that was it! Thank you so much!
